# Is there any query to find blocking sessions in the past? This is for Oracle database 12

Tags: oracle

I want to know which sessions were blocking other sessions, but views like `v$sessions` and `v$locks` only show me about active sessions, not sessions from other days.

I executed queries on `v$session` and `v$lock`, but didn´t show me the information that I require.

Comment: If you are licensed to use the AWR, you probably want `dba_hist_active_sess_history` https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/refrn/DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY.html#GUID-335EC838-FEA0-4872-9E14-67C5A1908B35

Comment: Thanks, I'll check that table. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have another wait-based sampling monitoring tool, ASH (`v$active_session_history` and `dba_hist_active_sess_history`) is the only place to get that information. Those won't, unfortunately, tell you all that much about the sessions themselves, but they do provide potentially enough for investigating your issue.

You'll want to pay special attention to the columns `event` and `blocking_*` cols. `current_obj#` joined to `dba_objects` will tell you what object was involved. If you want a bit of info on the blocking session, you can take the `blocking_session/blocking_session_serial#,blocking_inst_id` blocker key and requery ASH looking for these values in `session_id/session_serial#,inst_id` key cols. You can then join `user_id` to `dba_users` to get the username and you can also see the program, module and machine in ASH. There is, unfortunately, no full-blown `v$session`-style session history in Oracle (unless you custom build one yourself), so some details that could be useful (like osuser, logon time, etc..) you have to go without. You may not actually get any info on the blocker however if it took its lock out quickly and spent less than 10 seconds doing work before going idle. ASH will only record non-idle waits, so if a session is doing nothing, it doesn't show up in ASH, but it can still hold a lock.

As you query these, keep in mind that while `v$active_session_history` (very recent activity) will show 1 row per second of non-idle wait (or CPU) per process, the on-disk version of that, `dba_hist_active_sess_history` is a 1-out-of-10 sample of the former, so every row actually represents an average of 10 seconds of non-idle wait.   If you need to see SQL, you can join on `sql_id` to `dba_hist_sqltext` for cursors no longer in the shared pool. ASH/AWR is only configured to keep data for so long, so if you wait too long (a few weeks or a month perhaps, depending on the setting) the information will no longer be available.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a query that gives us a list of blocking sessions and the sessions that they are blocking:

```sql
select
   blocking_session,
   sid,
   serial#,
   wait_class,
   seconds_in_wait
from
   v$session
where
   blocking_session is not NULL
order by
   blocking_session;
```

| BLOCKING_SESSION | SID | SERIAL# | WAIT_CLASS | SECONDS_IN_WAIT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 148 | 135 | 61521 | Idle | 64 |